# How to loop output in python, pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to randomly select data on a quarterly basis and set the output in different csv files, and make this loop for several years. The following is an example of data.

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>Event number</th><th>Month</th><th>Year</th><th>Unauthorised activity</th><th>Theft and fraud (internal)</th><th>Theft and fraud (external)</th></tr><tr><td>72</td><td>1</td><td>2015</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>73</td><td>2</td><td>2015</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>74</td><td>3</td><td>2015</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>75</td><td>4</td><td>2015</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>76</td><td>5</td><td>2015</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>80</td><td>6</td><td>2015</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>81</td><td>7</td><td>2015</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>83</td><td>8</td><td>2015</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>84</td><td>9</td><td>2015</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>87</td><td>10</td><td>2015</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>90</td><td>11</td><td>2015</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>103</td><td>12</td><td>2015</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Here is my current code:

```
df = pd.read_pickle('data.pkl')
df.set_index(['Claim  Number'], inplace = True)

df2015q1 = df[(1 <= df.Month )&(df.Month <= 3) & (df.Year == 2015)]

df2015q1_random = df2015q1.sample(n=200)
df2015q1_random.sort_index(inplace=True)
df2015q1_random = df2015q1_random.drop(['Month', 'Year'], axis = 1)
df2015q1_random = df2015q1_random.drop_duplicates()

df2015q1_random.to_csv('2015Q1.csv')
```

The expected output for 2015 quarter 1 is 2015Q1.csv，for quarter 2 is 2015Q2.csv etc.

Currently, my output for a single stage is right, but I do not know how to write a loop for this. How can I do this for several years, say 2010 to 2016, and write the output in different files? Thanks.

Comment: Let me try to clarify this. All you're doing is changing the years on the fourth and last line of code right? If this is the case, then simply create a list with values [2010, 2011..] and loop over the values. Then your fourth line can use the direct integer value and for your last line you'll need to convert the input to a str.

If this is what you're looking for, then please respond and I'll make a nice answer out of it with a code sample.

Comment: First step before worrying about it looping, is to split this into a function that takes the date ranges as arguments (and determines the file name from those arguments). Then it will be much easier to call it repeatedly, and it should become obvious how to loop over a list of dates with the same function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
years = [2015,2016] 
qtrs = [1,2,3,4] 
for year in years:
    for qtr in qtrs:
        temp = df[(df.Month <= 3*qtr) (df.Month >= 3*(qtr-1)) & (df.Year == year)] 
        temp_random = temp.sample(n=200) 
        temp_random.sort_index(inplace=True) 
        temp_random = temp_random.drop(['Month', 'Year'], axis = 1) 
        temp_random = temp_random.drop_duplicates()
        temp_random.to_csv((str(year)+'Q'+str(qtr)+'.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks ,very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Let's create a function and use a list as inputs to make this happen. I haven't tested the code so you'll have to do that yourself. This is more to give you an idea how it can be done. Basically, you create a function for re-usability and afterwards you loop over a list of years to get a set of results.

```
# create a function that will report on a specific year
def save_file(df, year):
    dfq1 = df[(1 <= df.Month )&(df.Month <= 3) & (df.Year == year)]
    dfq1_random = dfq1.sample(n=200)
    dfq1_random.sort_index(inplace=True)
    dfq1_random = dfq1_random.drop(['Month', 'Year'], axis = 1)
    dfq1_random = dfq1_random.drop_duplicates()

    dfq1_random.to_csv(str(year) + 'Q1.csv')

# load the data and call your function for each year you want reported on
df = pd.read_pickle('data.pkl')
df.set_index(['Claim  Number'], inplace = True)

list_years = [2015, 2016] 
for year in list_years:
    save_file(df, year)
```

Comment: Thanks, I like the function for re-usability part. That is new to me.

Answer (score -1):

I would approach this with a `groupby` statement

```
import pandas
years_of_interest = [2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016]
data = {'Claim Number': ['1234x', '2345x', '34567x', '78910x', '87911x', '98732x'],
        'Month': [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 7],
        'Year': [2010, 2010, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2015]}

df = pandas.DataFrame(data).set_index('Claim Number'):
grouper = df.groupby('Year')
for year, data in grouper:
   if year in years_of_interest:
       q1_data = data[df.Month <=3]
       # Do your other work and save
```